# Can an Eclipse run configuration invoke Maven --resume-from on the selected project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm trying to create a run/debug configuration to continue at the point I left off using the `-rf` (`--resume-from`) syntax.

Tried the following in the "Goals" section:

```
-rf :${project_name} install
```

Was hoping this would allow me to select the project I want to resume from and then launch. But Eclipse complains:

> Could not find project to resume reactor build from: :${project_name}

Presumably this means Eclipse isn't expanding the [${project_name}](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm) variable. Has anyone found a way of doing this or am I barking up a blind alley?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of responses make me suspect there probably isn't a way to do this for a *selected* project. I ended up creating a run configuration for each project I might want to resume from.